# scp can't upload/download files even though ssh works

Tags: ssh, rsync, scp, remote, sftp

I can connect to my server using `ssh dziura` and it works as it should, but I have problems copying any files to/from the server using rsync/scp/sftp.

Scp:

```
$ scp dziura:/home/kossak/file_remote.txt .
$ scp ./file_local.txt dziura:/home/kossak/
lost connection
```

The first command returns 0 status, doesn't show any messages/errors and the file "file_remote.txt" is NOT copied to my local directory (I have rwx permissions to my local dir). The second command returns "lost connection"

Rsync:

```
$ rsync -Lr --partial --progress --rsh=ssh dziura:/home/kossak/file_remote.txt .
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [Receiver=3.1.0]
```

Sftp:

```
$ sftp dziura
Connection closed
```

I also checked `/var/log/auth.log` file (on the server) after running first scp command and it had lines:

```
Oct 27 20:26:37 dziura sshd[3027]: Accepted publickey for kossak from <MY_IP> port 34583 ssh2: RSA <...>
Oct 27 20:26:37 dziura sshd[3027]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user kossak by (uid=0)
Oct 27 20:26:38 dziura sshd[3075]: Received disconnect from <MY_IP>: 11: disconnected by user
Oct 27 20:26:38 dziura sshd[3027]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user kossak
```

SSH on the remote server works on standard 22 port.
I have root access to local and remote machines.
The remote server runs Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.
Locally I use Linux Mint 17.2.
Server name "dziura" is in `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host dziura
  HostName <IP_GOES_HERE>
  User kossak
  IdentityFile /home/kossak/.ssh/id_rsa_enc
```

Verbose log from `scp -vvv dziura:/home/kossak/file_remote.txt .`: http://pastebin.com/0DkeHEC3

Any ideas how to fix this problem? Thank you.

### -- EDIT --

I run my sshd in debug mode via: `sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -p 2222 -D -d -e` and from my local machine i tried to scp file: `scp -P 2222 file_local.txt dziura:`. The log on the remote server was: http://pastebin.com/xxji6ucL
Scp command also displayed some environmental variables before showing "lost connection".
Here's more verbose debugging: http://pastebin.com/HiJ8qB0Y

Comment: What do you have in server config? Do you have `sftp` subsystem set up correctly?  Is there `scp` binary on remote system?

Comment: Yes, remote server has rsync/scp/sftp commands. I don't know if sftp is setup correctly - does it matter for scp/rsync to work properly?

Comment: Can you post verbose log from some of the failed comands, for example `scp -vvv dziura:/home/kossak/file_remote.txt .`?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you can always fake a file transfer with something like `<file_local.txt ssh dziura 'cat >file_local.txt'`. (If that fails too, then it would be something really weird.)

Comment: @Jakuje http://pastebin.com/0DkeHEC3

Comment: @TomHunt doesn't work either. Also, weird thing is that ```ssh dziura 'pwd'``` doesn't display anything (when I run it on other servers I get the path in return).

Comment: This look really weird. Would `ssh -tt dziura 'pwd'` make any change? I don't see there any other difference then the TTY presence.

Comment: @Jakuje it is different - returns "Connection to <IP> closed." message.

Comment: The last idea is to run the server in debug mode and watch logs. And maybe what is missing, does `scp` work for you to other servers and from other clients to this server?

Comment: @Jakuje scp works from my machine to another server I call "is". It also works from "dziura" to "is". But it doesn't work from "is" to "dziura". So I guess it's the problem somewhere on the server "dziura". I will google how to put sshd in debug mode but probably tomorrow since I'm tired for now :)

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? ;-) Honestly, one cause of this could be recent library updates, and a clean restart of all services might correct the issue.

Comment: @ams I updated the system including ```sudo apt-get dist-upgrade``` also I rebooted the whole machine few times, but the problem persists.

Comment: @Jakuje I ran sshd in debug mode, tried scp a file to the server and here's the log: http://pastebin.com/xxji6ucL - does it say anything to you? :) I also updated my post with this info.

Comment: Can you try with `-ddd` to get more verbose info?

Comment: @Jakuje here's the result: http://pastebin.com/HiJ8qB0Y

Comment: Sorry. Still no idea. As a next step I would run the server under `valgrind` or `gdb` to see if some of the processes fails, but it is quite painful experience, but you can learn something new :) There is SIGCHLD which notes that the process ends (somehow), but I have no idea why it doesn't give you any data.

Comment: @jakuje Thank you very much for your time, though. gdb is a bit down on my list of things to learn about Linux, so I think I will just destroy this machine and set up everything anew (maybe Debian this time).

Comment: I have the exact same issue. did u fix it? can u remember how u dealt it, though its 3 years ago?

Comment: I think rebooting router fixed the issue!

Comment: @neckTwi I scrapped the machine and installed everything anew.